# Protractor version 5.2.0 - How to pass a specific key (Ex: TAB) as a parameter in sendkeys()?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I wanted to pass the key names as a parameter, to make it more reusable instead of hard coding.

Just something like below

```
function Keyboardaction(keys)
    {
    return browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.(keys)).perform();
    }

Keyboardaction(TAB);
```

Can anyone help on the same

Comment: btw the latest protractor is `6.0.0`

Comment: @Sergey Pleshakov  . Updated my title :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
function Keyboardaction(keys)
{
    return browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key[keys]).perform();
}

Keyboardaction("TAB");
```

but then you'll want to pass multiple keys, or chords, send it to particular element etc and this won't work for you. And all because the approach is fundamentally incorrect. But if it works for you, go for it