# How to customize sendKeys(protractor.Key.)

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, integrate

I tried to add the following function as a helper at the beginning

```
exports.EditTime = function (number) {
element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.number);
  element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
}
```

But it seems doesn't work if I assigned number as NUMPAD1, NUMPAD2 .....
Therefore, I changed the function into a switch case function which looks stupid...

```
exports.EditTime = function (number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD1);
    case 2:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD2);
    case 3:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD3);
    case 4:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD4);
    case 5:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD5);
    case 6:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD6);
    case 7:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD7);
    case 8:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD8);
    case 9:
      element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD9);
  }
  element(by.className('numberFormat p-inputtext p-component')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
  sleep(1000);
}
```

I am wondering if anyone has a better approach to implement such a function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protractor version 5.2.0 - How to pass a specific key (Ex: TAB) as a parameter in sendkeys()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626150/protractor-version-5-2-0-how-to-pass-a-specific-key-ex-tab-as-a-parameter-i)

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov's link contains the correct answer. Using the dot notation is basically accessing the `NUMPAD1` property of the `Key` object inside the `protractor` object. You want to pass a variable which contains a property name so you need to use square bracket notation like `protractor.Key[number]`